# Speeding up AngularJS: Reducing watches

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The same heavy-duty method "`quantityOf(garment)`" is called four times for each item in a set.

This means there's a big lag if someone clicks an item, it has to recalculate each of these.

Each `garment` from a collection called "`product list`" is listed out. When garments are added to an order, they are added to a collection `Order.lineitems`. The `quantityOf(garment)` method looks at how many times each garment is present `Order.lineitems`

The HTML:

```
<div ng-switch="orderCtrl.quantityOf(garment)" ng-class="{ 'clicked': orderCtrl.quantityOf(garment) > 0 }" ng-click="orderCtrl.addGarment(garment)">

  <button type="button" ng-show="orderCtrl.quantityOf(garment) > 0">
    &times;
  </button>

  <div ng-switch-when="0>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    {{orderCtrl.quantityOf(garment)}}&times;
  </div>

  <p>
    {{garment.name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

The 'heavy duty' method:
(Here _. refers to the lodash method https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex)

```
this.quantityOf = function(garment){
  var index = _.findIndex(this.order.lineitems, function(b){
    return b.id === garment.id;
  });

  if (index != -1){
    return this.order.lineitems[index].quantity
  } else {
    return 0
  }
};
```

I simply can't think of a simpler, lighter way to implement this functionality.

**Attempts at a solution**
Should I create a new angular array called "presentItems" that keeps track of the ids that were added to the lineitems? Perhaps it would be faster to search through?

Should I add an attribute to the `productlist` collection, a boolean called "added", that I can use to reference whether this item has been added or not?

Comment: I would instead try to find a way to not need to execute quantityOf to get the quantity. Or at least store the result of the first time you call it on the garment so that you only need to do it once. There's no sense in executing it four times when all four times will have the same result.

Comment: One option would be to add a quantity property to all garments defaulted to 0, and when a garment is added or removed to or from the order, the quantity property on the garment gets updated too.

Comment: var index=_.pluck(this.order.lineitems, 'id').indexOf(garment.id); would likely be a faster way to find the index, since it uses a native for half of the work and pluck() gets more optimization than a user-land function

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUAL SOLUTION**

The problem above turned out to be a red herring! While it's nice to have less watchers - the above was clearly clunky, the real issue was the 300ms delay when you press a button on iOS.

If you're using Angular, here's the solution
http://joegaudet.com/angular/mobile/2013/07/22/fast-clicks-with-angular-js.html

Otherwise, search for "google fast button" - there are some JS libraries that wrap up the google code.

**Solution**

Thanks for all of your help.

This was the solution that worked for me: adding a boolean called "added" to the `garment` in `product list`. It's weird to be modifying the product list, but it's fast and it works.

HTML

```
<div ng-switch="garment.added" ng-class="{ 'clicked': garment.added }" ng-click="orderCtrl.addGarment(garment)">

  <button ng-click="orderCtrl.removeGarment(garment); $event.stopPropagation()" ng-show="garment.added" >
    &times;
  </button>

  <div ng-switch-default type="button" class="btn btn-link add-button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="true" type="button" class="btn btn-link add-button">
    {{orderCtrl.quantityOf(garment)}}&times;
  </div>

  <p>
  {{garment.name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
function addGarment(garment){
    var index = _.findIndex(this.order.lineitems, function(b){
      return b.id === garment.id;
    });

    if (index != -1){
      this.order.lineitems[index].quantity += 1;
    } else {
      garment.added = true;  // ADDED
      var new_garment = garment;
      new_garment['quantity'] = 1;
      this.order.lineitems.push(garment);
    }
  }


  function removeGarment(garment) {
    var index = _.findIndex(this.order.lineitems, function(b){
      return b.id === garment.id;
    });
    if (index == -1) return;

    if (this.order.lineitems[index].quantity > 1){
      this.order.lineitems[index].quantity -= 1;
    } else {
      garment.added = false; // ADDED
      this.order.lineitems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```